# List OrderBy is not working in case of non-primitive type

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

```
public class Sales : Resource
{
    public Channel ChannelName { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class Channel:Resource
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

List sort is working fine for primitive(string) property like Type but not for non-primitive like Channel. Any suggestions please ?

```
List<Sales> result = GetListofSales(); // list of sales

result = result.OrderBy(x =>x.Type).ThenBy(**y => y.ChannelName.code**).ToList();
```

Comment: What's the issue? You can implement `IComparable<Channel>` in the `Channel` class or you can implement and pass `IComparer<Channel>`, but the code you posted is just fine for me.

Comment: [System.ArgumentException] = {"At least one object must implement IComparable."}

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes you are right Ivan.. many thanks :)

Comment: I mean, what's the issue with using `y.ChannelName.Code` rather than just `y.ChannelName`? Since your `Channel` class probably has multiple properties, specifying which one to use in the OrderBy/ThenBy sounds like a correct approach. Anyway :)

Comment: For me the list is ordered correclty, are you data from a DbContext?
If yes try to add the virtual keyword on Channel, if not, maybe having the value of Resource would be helpfull

Comment: You can simply override `ToString()` method with a string representation of desired order and then call `result.OrderBy(x =>x.Type).ThenBy(y => y.ChannelName.ToString()).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks all for your enthusiastic replies.. Its working after implementing @IvanStoev suggestion to implement IComparable.

Answer (score 2):

Actually,  I tried it and it sorts the data fine, in the below sample data

List list = new List();

```
        Sales sales = new Sales();
        sales.ChannelName = new Channel { Code = "B" };
        sales.Type = "C";
        list.Add(sales);

        sales = new Sales();
        sales.ChannelName = new Channel { Code = "AB" };
        sales.Type = "C";
        list.Add(sales);

        sales = new Sales();
        sales.ChannelName = new Channel { Code = "A" };
        sales.Type = "A";
        list.Add(sales);

        sales = new Sales();
        sales.ChannelName = new Channel { Code = "C" };
        sales.Type = "B";
        list.Add(sales);

        sales = new Sales();
        sales.ChannelName = new Channel { Code = "D" };
        sales.Type = "D";
        list.Add(sales);
```

The results will be 
[image]

So, as you can see, it ordered A, then B and since there are 2 sales with Type = C, it ordered them according to the channel code and although channel B is added first then channel AB, the results are showing channel AB then B which means the second level order by has been applied